# Configuring Wireless Network

Tags: wifi, vyatta

I have vyataa  router on VMware  with 2 interfaces  eth0 and eth1

eth0 is facing the internet

eth0 is in Nat mode with dhcp on

eth1 is in bridged mode with my ethernet with ip 10.0.2.34/24

The ethernet card is at ip 10.0.2.95/24

i have defined the nat rule. Hence internet is available at eth1 too.

Now i am connecting a wireless router at "eth1" iball router, I have connected the router using a cable to the ethernet interface of my  laptop.

I have configured the WAN connection type as "Static IP" and given "10.0.2.34/24"

All the clients that connect using wireless router cannot connect to the internet though.

Could anyone provide me a solution for this..

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

"WAN connection type as "Static IP" and given "10.0.2.34/24"" - if this is the configuration on your router, then it looks like you may have an IP conflict with "eth1 is in bridged mode with my ethernet with ip 10.0.2.34/24"